# Is it OK to pass an async function to setImmediate in order to call an arbitrary function asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, promise

I want to call a given function asynchronously.  The wrapper function tryCallAsync is one way of doing this.  This approach works.  However, it requires that the callback for setImmediate to be an async function.  This *seems* wrong, as the callback is returning a Promise that is not used.  Is it wrong to pass an async function to setImmediate for this purpose?

```
async function tryCallAsync(fn, ...args) {

    return new Promise((r, j) => {

        setImmediate(async () => {

            try {
                r(await fn(...args));
            }
            catch (e) {
                j(e);
            }
        })
    })
}

//  Using tryCallAsync

let resolveAsync = tryCallAsync(()=>{
    return new Promise((r,j)=>{
        setImmediate(()=>r('resolveAsync'));
    });
})

resolveAsync.then((resolve)=>console.log(resolve));

let resolve = tryCallAsync(()=>{
    return 'resolve';
});

resolve.then((resolve)=>console.log(resolve));
```

NB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3Nh350b6S4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong, for multiple reasons:

- `setImmediate` doesn't handle the returned promise, especially it doesn't deal with errors<sup>1</sup>
- Don't put business logic in asynchronous (non-promise) callbacks when using promises. Settle a promise from there, nothing else.

<sub>1: And even while your particular callback never rejects the returned promise due to the `try`/`catch`, it still *feels* wrong</sub>

Your function should be written as

```
async function tryCallAsync(fn, ...args) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setImmediate(resolve);
    });
    return fn(...args);
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach I've seen.  You wrote, "Don't put business logic in asynchronous (non-promise) callbacks when using promises. Settle a promise from there, nothing else."  I've read that several times and I cannot figure out what you meant.  Can you elaborate on your meaning?  What specifically are you referring to as "business logic"?

Comment: In a callback-based API, you need to put the code (business logic) that should run after the asynchronous action is completed inside the callback. In a promise-based API, you put the code in a `.then()` callback or after an `await`. When you want to write promise-based code, you need to [promisify the callback APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572), and should do that by placing nothing but `if (err) reject(err) else resolve(result)` in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't waste a Promise, however, still, it's not as performant as the conventional way of doing this.

```
function tryCallAsync(fn, ...args) {

    return new Promise((r, j) => {

        setImmediate(() => {

            (async function () {

                return await fn(...args);

            })().then(r).catch(j);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "waste a promise", this approach actually creates even more promises than the original :-) You could simplify it to `return new Promise(resolve => { setImmediate(() => { resolve((async () => fn(...args))()); }); });`

Comment: @Bergi  I was just referring to the async function that I had passed to the setImmediate.  Thank you for sharing that code!  I was perplexed at how it handles errors, but I think I see it now.  It gives me a lot to think about :-)